# How to fix "transform with key of translatex must be a number" error in React Native?

Tags: animation, react-native, transform

I 'm trying to make a translate animation in React Native.

Here is my code

```
const scrollX = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

<Animated.ScrollView
     horizontal
     snapToInterval={width}
     onScroll={Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
        { useNativeDriver: false }
        )}
     scrollEventThrottle={16}
  ></Animated.ScrollView>

  <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX: multiply(scrollX, -1) }] }}>
          <Text>Some text</Text>
  </Animated.View>
```

I am getting this error `transform with key of translatex must be a number`

If I change `multiply(scrollX, -1)` to `scrollX` the animation is reversed,

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: use interpolation then using extrapolation property you can mention strings as well like '0deg' to '360deg'

Answer (score 34):

i had this issue,Just because i forgot to give **Animated.View**

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `Animated` from `react-native` and not from `react-native-reanimated`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the import of `multiply` from `react-native-reanimated` to `Animated`

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = () => {

    const translation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    useEffect(()=> {
        Animated.timing(translation, {
            toValue: 200,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
            <Animated.View style={{
                width: 150, height: 150, backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: 8, margin: 10, 
                transform: [{translateX:  translation}]
            }} />
        </>
    );
}
export default test;
```

Need to Give where you want to do Animation -> Animated.[Component Name] -> E.g: Animated.View   / Animated.Text / Animated.Button